# Are there large $n$-queens solutions without 3-in-a-line?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, chessboard

Wikipedia references: [N-queens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_queens_puzzle) & [No-3-in-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-three-in-line_problem)

The 4-queens board is few enough pieces that it never has three queens on the same line

```
·-------·
|  ×    |
|      ×|
|×      |
|    ×  |
·-------·
```

But even by the 5-queens boards, the "put them a knight move apart" general pattern for solutions starts showing up, as both (modulo symmetry) solutions have 3-in-a-line:

```
·---------·
|×        |
|    ×    |
|        ×|
|  ×      |
|      ×  |
·---------·

·---------·
|  ×      |
|        ×|
|    ×    |
|×        |
|      ×  |
·---------·
```

And the only 6-queens board has two lines already:

```
·-----------·
|  ×        |
|      ×    |
|          ×|
|×          |
|    ×      |
|        ×  |
·-----------·
```

There's one 7-queens solution with only a single line

```
·-------------·
|  ×          |
|      ×      |
|×            |
|            ×|
|        ×    |
|    ×        |
|          ×  |
·-------------·
```

but most have more.

Is it possible that a large board can have arrangement that solves both the $n$-queens problem **and** the no-three-in-line problem?  Or does the knight-move structure of $n$-queens solutions always end up making lines of three-or-more pieces?

Comment: You might have added that Wikipedia shows that one out of the $12$ fundamental solutions for $8$ queens has none in a line.

Comment: The number of solutions with and without symmetry reduction is

\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16\\\hline
\text{with}&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&4&5&12&53&174&555&2344&8968\\
\text{w/o}&0&0&2&0&0&0&8&32&40&96&410&1392&4416&18752&71486
\end{array}

So it seems there are solutions for large $n$. [Here](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4642059.java)'s the code. Neither of those two sequences is in OEIS.

Comment: And somehow I totally missed the note on the wikipedia page that "Solution 10 has the additional property that no three queens are in a straight line." 

Sorry for the noise, and thanks for going the extra mile and giving the numbers of solutions!